# Trying to use Image from "next/Image" throws a TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a component that looks like this:

```
import React, { FC, ImgHTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import NextImage from "next/image";
import checkInViewIntersectionObserver from "@/utils/isInViewPortIntersectionObserver";
import PlaceIcon from "./PlaceIcon";

export interface NcImageProps extends ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> {
  containerClassName?: string;
}

const NcImage: FC<NcImageProps> = ({
  containerClassName = "",
  alt = "nc-imgs",
  src = "",
  className = "object-cover w-full h-full",
  ...args
}) => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  const _containerRef = useRef(null);

  const [__src, set__src] = useState("");
  const [imageLoaded, setImageLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let _imageEl: HTMLImageElement | null = null;

    isMounted.current = true;

    const _imageOnViewPort = () => {
      if (!src) {
        _handleImageLoaded();
        return true;
      }
      _imageEl = new Image();
      if (_imageEl) {
        _imageEl.src = src;
        _imageEl.addEventListener("load", _handleImageLoaded);
      }
      return true;
    };

    const _handleImageLoaded = () => {
      if (!isMounted.current) return;
      setImageLoaded(true);
      set__src(src);
    };

    const _checkInViewPort = () => {
      if (!_containerRef.current) return;
      checkInViewIntersectionObserver({
        target: _containerRef.current,
        options: {
          root: null,
          rootMargin: "0%",
          threshold: 0,
        },
        freezeOnceVisible: true,
        callback: _imageOnViewPort,
      });
    };

    const _initActions = async () => {
      _checkInViewPort();
    };

    _initActions();
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, [src]);

  const renderLoadingPlaceholder = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className={`${className} flex items-center justify-center bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-neutral-6000 text-neutral-100 dark:text-neutral-500`}
      >
        <div className="h-2/4 max-w-[50%]">
          <PlaceIcon />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={`nc-NcImage ${containerClassName}`} data-nc-id="NcImage" ref={_containerRef}>
      {__src && imageLoaded ? (
        <NextImage src={__src} className={className} alt={alt} {...args} />
      ) : (
        renderLoadingPlaceholder()
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NcImage;
```

It was originally using `<img ...` instead of `NextImage` and things were fine. I wanted to change it to Next.js' `Image` component. As soon as I did that, I got the following error:

```
Type '{ crossOrigin?: "" | "anonymous" | "use-credentials" | undefined; decoding?: "async" | "auto" | "sync" | undefined; height?: string | number | undefined; loading?: "eager" | "lazy" | undefined; ... 263 more ...; alt: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ src: string | StaticImport; alt: string; width?: SafeNumber | undefined; height?: SafeNumber | undefined; fill?: boolean | undefined; loader?: ImageLoader | undefined; ... 11 more ...; lazyRoot?: string | undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'width' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SafeNumber | undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SafeNumber | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

I'm not entirely sure how to fix it though since I am not using `width` anywhere.

I thought of just getting it from the inputs to `NcImage` and then changing its type:

```
  const newWidth = typeof width === 'number' ? SafeNumber(width) : width;
```

But I'm not sure what SafeNumber is or where to import it from. What is the proper way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are rendering a Next.js `Image` tag, use the corresponding props type, which is `ImageProps`, like so:

```
import { ImageProps } from "next/image";
```

```
export interface NcImageProps extends ImageProps {
  containerClassName?: string;
}
```

With this, your error goes away.

Comment: This makes sense, I should have seen it. But I believe it will create an issue with `typescript`s `Image` in this line: `_imageEl = new Image()` specifically when assigning a new `src` that has to be of type string. I thus had to update the command like this `set__src(src.toString());`

Additionally it causes an issue with `alt`. As you can see I have `alt = "nc-imgs",` so I was hoping  I wouldn't have to call it every time I use `NcImage` this does not seem to be the case since I get `Type error: Property 'alt' is missing in type ..'NcImageProps'.` I'm not sure how to solve this yet.

Comment: Regarding the problem with `alt`, just make it optional with `export interface NcImageProps extends Omit<ImageProps, "alt"> {
  containerClassName?: string;
  alt?: string;
}`. Of course, you keep the default `alt = "nc-imgs"` and pass it to `NextImage` as there it's required.

Comment: For the `src`, if from the outside you would always get a string, you can do the same thing as `alt`, omit it from `ImageProps` and add it as a string in the type body.

Comment: Coming back at this. It seems that your suggestion indeed removes all errors, and the project builds. It was only later though that I noticed that all `NcImage` components display no image at all on `build && start`,  `run dev` on the other hand fails to load the page and throws the following error "error - Error: Image with src "/_next/static/media/hero-right.4859d624.png" is missing required "width" property." I will investigate further and see what the source of the issue is, possibly revisiting the question if there is something useful to add.

Comment: This is related to how `Image` from Next.js works. You need to give a `width` and height or use the [fill](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#fill) property.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from your props spread `{...args}` where it defines `width` in its interface as inherited from normal `img.width` even though it's not really being passed down the `<NextImage {...args}/>` component.

---

It's because Next Image is now using `` type SafeNumber = number | `${number}` ``, so if you are storing the number-ish img attributes as strings, you will need to convert or type cast them to a number.

```
<Image
  width={Number(myStringValue)}
/>
```

Normal img:

```
width?: number | string | undefined;
```

Next Image:

```
width?: SafeNumber | undefined;
// or
width?: number | `${number}` | undefined;
```

```
type SafeNumber = number | `${number}`;
```